# Prove a function is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have to prove that 
$T : M_{2x2} \rightarrow P_{3}$ defined below is a linear transformation:

$T \bigg(\bigg( \begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\bigg)\bigg) = (a+b) +(a-2c)x+(c-d)x^2+(a-c-d)x^3$

I understand that, generally, I need to show that is closed under addition and closed under multiplication, but I am not sure where to start for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

For closed under addition, let $A, B \in M_{2 \times 2}$.

- First compute $T(A)$ explicitly as the entries of $A$.
- Compute $T(B)$.
- Compute $A+B$.
- Compute $T(A+B)$
- Compute $T(A)+T(B)$.
- Check if $T(A)+T(B)=T(A+B)$.

Comment: Can you show how to apply that to this specific problem? I understand that those are the steps I need to take but I'm not sure how to fit them with this problem.

Comment: Let $A= \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1\\ c_1 & d_1 \end{bmatrix}$, compute $T(A)$. $B= \begin{bmatrix} a_2 & b_2\\ c_2 & d_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and go on....

Comment: I'm sorry but can you walk me through the problem, if you don't mind? It's just not connecting for me.

Comment: where are you stuck at computing $T(A)$?

Comment: Yes! I'm not sure to compute it.

Comment: $T \bigg(\bigg( \begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\bigg)\bigg) = (a+b) +(a-2c)x+(c-d)x^2+(a-c-d)x^3$ what do you think $T \bigg(\bigg( \begin{matrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1\end{matrix}\bigg)\bigg)$ should be equal to?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: can you evaluate $T \bigg(\bigg( \begin{matrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{matrix}\bigg)\bigg)$?

Comment: Okay, I got addition. For multiplication, how would you set it up?

Comment: Compute $T(A)$,compute $kT(A)$,  compute $kA$, compute $T(kA)$, compute. check that $kT(A)=T(kA)$.

Comment: Would $A = \bigg(\bigg( \begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\bigg)\bigg)$ or would you substitute in $a_1,b_1,c_1, d_1$

Comment: either is fine, they are just symbols, previously I introduce more symbols as you have to deal with two matrices and I think preserving $a,b,c,d$ makes things easier.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the help.